# How to create sum of list items plus data validation in Google Spreadsheet forumla

Tags: sum, google-sheets

I am trying to create sums for each category as I add things to this expense list. [image]

So basically for each category "Brian" "Bobby" "Gas" etc, I want to create a sum. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help. I'm a noob at these spreadsheet formulas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `SUMIIF()` function to sum based on a condition ([Reference](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093583)). 
For example: `=SUMIF($C:$C, $E:$E=H1)` if you want to sum column C based on the category in Column E